# cuantas veces entra una palabra en una linea .docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Estoy haciendo un programita para imprimir unas etiquetas de esta manera:

nombre apellido nombre apellido
nombre apellido nombre apellido
nombre apellido nombre apellido
nombre apellido                                                                                      nombre apellido

pero con algunos nombres me pasa esto :

nombre apellido nombre apellido nombre
apellido nombre apellido nombre apellido
nombre apellido nombre apellido nombre
apellido nombre apellido nombre apellido
nombre apellido nombre apellido nombre

la solución que se me ocurre es contar cuantas veces puedo poner la cadena en la lineal pero estoy buscando y no encuentro nada :

```
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Mm

def crear_etiquetas_por_cantidad(nombres, cantidad):
    document = Document()

    style = document.styles['Normal']
    font = style.font
    font.size = Pt(14)
    section = document.sections[0]
    section.page_height = Mm(297)
    section.page_width = Mm(210)

    etiquetas = ''
    suma = 0
    for i in range(cantidad):
            if i== 0:
                etiquetas += f"{nombres}     "
                suma = suma + len(etiquetas)
                print(suma)
            else:
                etiquetas += f" {nombres}     "
    
    
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(etiquetas)
    paragraph.space_after = Mm(0)

    section = document.sections[0]
    section.left_margin = Mm(5)
    section.right_margin = Mm(5)
    section.top_margin = Mm(10)
    section.bottom_margin = Mm(10)
    paragraph.paragraph_format.left_indent = Mm(5)
    paragraph.paragraph_format.right_indent = Mm(5)

    document.save('etiquetas_por_hojas.docx')

def crear_etiquetas_por_cantidad_de_hojas(nombres, cantidad_hojas):
    document = Document()

    style = document.styles['Normal']
    font = style.font
    font.size = Pt(14)
    section = document.sections[0]
    section.page_height = Mm(297)
    section.page_width = Mm(210)

    etiquetas = ''
    cantidad_hojas = cantidad_hojas * 4280
    suma = 0
    while(suma <= cantidad_hojas):
            if suma == 0:
                etiquetas += f"{nombres}     "
                suma =len(etiquetas)
                print(suma)
            else:
                etiquetas += f"{nombres}     "
                suma = len(etiquetas)
                
    
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(etiquetas)
    paragraph.space_after = Mm(0)
    section = document.sections[0]
    section.left_margin = Mm(5)
    section.right_margin = Mm(5)
    section.top_margin = Mm(5)
    section.bottom_margin = Mm(5)
    paragraph.paragraph_format.left_indent = Mm(0)
    paragraph.paragraph_format.right_indent = Mm(0)
    document.save('etiquetas_por_cantidad.docx')

def abrir_archivo(nombre_archivo):
    import os
    os.system(nombre_archivo)

def main():
    nombres = input("Ingresa los nombres que quieres imprimir en las etiquetas (separados por espacios): ")
    caracteres = len(nombres)
    print(caracteres)
    #cantidad = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de veces que quieres que se imprima cada nombre: "))
    cantidad_hojas = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de hojas que quieres imprimir: "))
    #crear_etiquetas_por_cantidad(nombres, cantidad)
    crear_etiquetas_por_cantidad_de_hojas(nombres,cantidad_hojas) 
    
    print("Se han creado las etiquetas. Por favor, revisa el archivo etiquetas_por_cantidad.docx.")
    abrir_archivo('etiquetas_por_cantidad.docx')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Según la tipografía puede que las letras no tengan el mismo ancho

Comment: ¿Tabuladores en las cuatro posiciones que deseas?

Answer (score 0):

lo resolví de esta manera dividendo el "nombre y apellido" por categorías:

si el len(nombre y apellido) es menor de 20 es frec 3 "se ordena en 4 columnas"
si el len(nombre y apellido) esta entre 20 y 25 es frec 2 "se ordena en 3 columnas"
si el len(nombre y apellido) es mayor de 25 es frec 1 "se ordena en 2 columnas"

No se si seria la mejor manera de resolverlo pero estoy bastante conforme con el resultado.